# Allow Chrome app through windows firewall

Tags: google-chrome, sockets, udp, google-chrome-app, firewall

I am learning to make chrome app which will receive UDP packets from remote device. All works perfectly fine, however, in order to receive packets from remote device I need to turn off windows firewall.

Now the problem is that I do not see a way to add this app to pass firewall exception. Because I only see option to allow Chrome through firewall, not any of its apps.

What is the solution / workaround to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't get any answer, the best possible solution I could find so far is to add the port on which my chrome app will listen to firewall inbound rules. I didn't know this was possible until i read this article https://www.thewindowsclub.com/block-open-port-windows-8-firewall

However I still don't consider it the right solution because lets say I publish my app online for other people, it will not be convenient for them to be adding rules to their firewalls.

I am sure there must be a better solution.